Transmon charge dispersion calculation
In the literature the charge dispersion of the Cooper Pair Box in the transmon regime is always stated to be
$$\epsilon_m \approx (-1)^m E_C \dfrac{2^{4m+5}}{m!}\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\left(\dfrac{E_J}{2E_C}\right)^{\frac{m}{2}+\frac{3}{4}}e^{-\sqrt{8E_j/E_C}}$$
with $E_C, E_J$ the charging energy and josephson energy, respectively.
Can someone give a detailed explanation of how this is calculated?
